# Undefined index error in php.....help me please

Tags: php

This is the error:

> Notice: Undefined index: $product_title in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MyShop\admin_area\insert_product.php on line 148
>
> Notice: Undefined index: $product_cat in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MyShop\admin_area\insert_product.php on line 149
>
> Notice: Undefined index: $product_brand in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MyShop\admin_area\insert_product.php on line 150
>
> Notice: Undefined index: $product_price in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MyShop\admin_area\insert_product.php on line 151
>
> Notice: Undefined index: $product_desc in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MyShop\admin_area\insert_product.php on line 152
>
> Notice: Undefined index: $product_keywords in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MyShop\admin_area\insert_product.php on line 153
>
> Notice: Undefined index: $product_image in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MyShop\admin_area\insert_product.php on line 156
>
> Notice: Undefined index: $product_image in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MyShop\admin_area\insert_product.php on line 157
>   insert into products
>   (product_cat,product_brand,product_title,product_price,product_desc,product_image,product_keywords)
>   values ('','','','','','','')

This is the code:

```
if(isset($_POST['insert_post'])){
    $product_title = $_POST['$product_title'];
    $product_cat = $_POST['$product_cat'];
    $product_brand = $_POST['$product_brand'];
    $product_price = $_POST['$product_price'];
    $product_desc = $_POST['$product_desc'];
    $product_keywords = $_POST['$product_keywords'];

    $product_image = $_FILES['$product_image']['name'];
    $product_image_tmp = $_FILES['$product_image']['tmp_name'];

     echo $insert_product = "insert into products 
     (product_cat,product_brand,product_title,product_price,product_desc,product_image,product_keywords) values ('$product_cat','$product_brand','$product_title','$product_price','$product_desc','$product_image','$product_keywords')";
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: $source_code in question - nah, seriously, did you forget to attach your code to the question?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be, you are using an array with $product_image as array key, but ther is no array key $product_image.

1) try

```
if(array_key_exists($product_image,$array)){
   // code in the error-lines (148,149,150, .....
}
```